# Is there a way to compare lists of gradients?

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, gradient

I have evenly spaced time-series graphs with years on the x-axis (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,..2010) and no. of patients who visited clinics A, B, C, and D on the y-axis (in four separate graphs). I want to compare the difference in the growth of clinics. I calculated the gradient of the list of the no. of patients visited using np.gradient() for each clinic. I'm not sure how to compare the list of slopes (change in the no. of patients over time).

This is sample data and the calculated gradients.

```
year = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]

A = [12, 14, 36, 45]
np.gradient(A) 
array([ 2. , 12. , 15.5,  9. ])

B = [2, 10, 8, 24]
np.gradient(B)
array([ 8.,  3.,  7., 16.])

C = [8, 8, 15, 14]
np.gradient(C)
array([ 0. ,  3.5,  3. , -1. ])

D = [0, 12, 0, 6]
np.gradient(D)
array([12.,  0., -3.,  6.])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use matplotlib to create a rough sketch of four arrays on a graph to compare the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(A)
plt.plot(B)
plt.plot(C)
plt.plot(D)
plt.show()
```

You would have to construct the figure based on your year data and the amount of people which would then create the slops.

or use the gradients:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
plt.plot(np.gradient(A))
plt.plot(np.gradient(B))
plt.plot(np.gradient(C))
plt.plot(np.gradient(D))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did plot the gradients. But how to compare the graphs? What should I be looking for in the graph to compare two cases, let's say A and B? How to use the plot to compare the gradients?

Comment: I guess, what is the question and output for the comparison of those gradients? What specifically using the change in patient numbers over time? Personally, I would throw my arrays into a DataFrame to compare and then plot to show visuals

Comment: I'm trying to comment on the growth of clinics with respect to the no. of years. Growth is the number of patients visited. Since it changes over time for all the clinics, how to compute the net growth and compare the clinics?

Comment: I think I am finding it difficult to interpret the visualization. I am not sure what's the indicator of the absolute larger growth of one clinic in comparison to another.

Comment: can you update the question with the raw data that you are using? I think it may be best to throw it into a DataFrame and do your compare using pandas functions - then you can get a better sense probably of trying to see the delta

Comment: @Sonu you should ask a specific question about programming, here it looks like you do not really know what your are expecting. I'm afraid your question is out of the scope of stackoverflow